# Payflow Link Gateway Timing Out & Information entered incorrect. Try again

Tags: time, paypal, out

I'm having the most trouble with Paypal. We already have a system set up that is working our live site, but I created a test-only Payflow account for testing configured exactly how we have it in live, but it keeps timing out or giving me the error

> "Information entered incorrect. Try again.". The code has not changed.

Just yesterday before I left for the day it was working for once. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**Posting to this URL: https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/**

Login = My Login

Partner = PayPal

Amount = 5

Type = S

I have turned everything as "OPTIONAL" as far as address and billing goes. All that displays is the credit card number and expiration, but after it gives me the "Information entered incorrect. Try again." it displays a radio button that asks if the address is the same as the shipping. if I click different it does nothing, I think it should at least drop down with some other fields.

Payflow manager:
In Payflow manager if i try a test transaction under Virtual Terminal > Test Single Transaction it gives me this error:

Tender Type: Credit Card

Transaction: Sale

Card Number: 371449635398431

Mode: Test

I give it $5, nothing else filled in:

> Result Code:  104 Response Message:   Timeout waiting for Processor
>   response

It's a project I need to finish as quickly as possible but looks like Paypal isn't letting this happen. Also, I am using the test credit card numbers found in the docs.

Test link: http://cityoftemplates.com/email_process_test/tests/clientCheckout/

Answer (score 0):

The gateway with no changes to what I had done earlier started working.

I assume it was some kind of maintenance or downtime caused by POODLE (SSLv4 bug) that made it go down all morning.